# Obwohl und Verwendung dessen Synonyme

Tags: conjunction

Nach stundenlangem Recherchieren nach dem Unterschied zwischen obwohl/obgleich/wenngleich/obzwar/wiewohl/obschon stehe ich immer noch auf dem Schlauch.

Könnt ihr mir den Unterschied erläutern ? Danke

Comment: Noch eine Frage.... welche Konjunktionen benutzt man im Alltag nicht ? Ich möchte nämlich nicht komisch, oder genauer gesagt noch komischer :D, angeguckt werden, wenn ich spreche.
Vielen Dank

Comment: Bei allen außer dem ersten Beispiel wirst du wohl schräg angeschaut.

Comment: Danke für deine Antwort... das erklärt vieles!!

Comment: Was hast du denn soweit schon verstanden? Was genau ist noch unklar? Gibt es konkrete Beispiele, wo die dir über die Verwendung nicht sicher bist? Wenn jetzt jemand ins Blaue hinein aufschreibt, was ihm zum Thema einfällt, wird das nicht hinreichender sein, als das, was das Internet eh schon zu bieten hat.

Comment: Das war ein Witz, dass die Leute schräg anschauen!

Comment: Ich habe jetzt auch stundenlang recherchiert. Hat das geholfen?

Comment: Du solltest eigentlich eine Frage posten. Ich sehe hier keine Frage. Ich lese nur eine Aussage darüber wo du stehst. Wenn du keine Frage stellst, wird deine "Frage" geschlossen.

Comment: Ich habe schon die Frage geschrieben, aber sie ist irgendwie weg, nachdem ich die Frage gepostet habe. :/

Answer (score 6):

Alle Wörter, die du gegeben hast, sind in der gleichen Synonymgruppe.

### [Obwohl](https://www.dwds.de/wb/obwohl)

**Beispiel**

> wir setzten weiterhin alles ein, obwohl wir wussten, dass es erfolglos
>   war

**Worthäufigkeit**

[image]

---

### [Obgleich](https://www.dwds.de/wb/obgleich)

**Beispiel**

> wir erkannten sie nicht, obgleich sie schon einmal bei uns gewesen war

**Worthäufigkeit**

[image]

---

### [Wenngleich](https://www.dwds.de/wb/wenngleich)

**Beispiel**

> sie nickte zustimmend, wenngleich sie es nicht recht verstanden hatte

**Worthäufigkeit**

[image]

---

### [Obzwar](https://www.dwds.de/wb/obzwar) (veraltet)

**Beispiel**

> [ich] erzählte niemandem an Bord von der seltsamen Begegnung, obzwar die Versuchung keine geringe war

**Worthäufigkeit**

[image]

---

### [Wiewohl](https://www.dwds.de/wb/wiewohl) (veraltet)

**Beispiel**

> ich beherrschte mich, wiewohl es mir nicht leicht fiel

**Worthäufigkeit**

[image]

---

### [Obschon](https://www.dwds.de/wb/obschon)

**Beispiel**

> Minna, die ... nie anders als »das Mädchen« genannt wurde, obschon sie selber an die Siebzig zählte

**Worthäufigkeit**

[image]

---

Wenn *Obwohl* ist bei weitem am populärsten, sind *Obzwar* und *Wiewohl* veraltet.

[Quelle](https://www.dwds.de/)

---

Nach langen Diskussionen, ob die Grafiken benutzt werden dürfen, habe ich DWDS kontaktiert und ihre Antwort ist wie folgt:

<sub>Eine generelle Aussage, ob und wie das erlaubt ist, können wir da pauschal nicht treffen, aber ich sag mal so: Wenn es nur einen (relevanten) Ausschnitt betrifft -- also keine komplette Kopie einer DWDS-Seite darstellt --, dann gerne; und es wäre schön, wenn es einen entsprechenden Verweis (Link) auf die Seite im DWDS gäbe</sub>